# Deserialize variables in Azure Devops API in C#

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am using Azure Devops API to read the variables groups in C#.
I am able to deserialize it into a custom object (with same properties) as long as i dont include the variables. Since variables seems like a dynamic object i am not able to deserialize it.
Here is my sample JSON reponse:

```
{
"id":77,
"type":"Vsts",
"variables":{
   "key1":{"value":"value1"},
   "key2":{"value":"value2"}
 }
}
```

Here is my custom object

```
public class AzureVariableGroup
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    //public string variables { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an efficient way to deserialize the whole object including "variables"

Comment: Have you tried to declare "variables" as a dictionary? in your AzureVariableGroup class.